# The file is not existed when upload PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to do file conversion from excel to csv. the thing is, file is somehow not existed and the program did not recognize it as excel file. I dont know what to do.
[This is the main page (see I use excel file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hsOb.png)
[The outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO2GX.png). This is the link of

```
<?php
$folder_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file_dir = $folder_dir . ($_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]);
$target_file_ext = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file_dir, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$target_file_name = $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"];

$output_dir = "outputs/";

// Check if file already exists
if ($target_file_ext != "xls" && $target_file_ext != "xlsx") {
    header("Location: error.php");
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file_dir)) {
        if ($target_file_ext == "xls") {
            $target_file_name_without_ext = substr($target_file_name, 0, -4);
            $output_file_dir = $output_dir . $target_file_name_without_ext;
        }
        if ($target_file_ext == "xlsx") {
            $target_file_name_without_ext = substr($target_file_name, 0, -5);
            $output_file_dir = $output_dir . $target_file_name_without_ext;
        }

        $output_file_name = $target_file_name_without_ext . ".csv";
        exec("java -jar exceltocsvasg.jar $target_file_dir $output_file_dir");
        header("Location: success_convert_file.php?converted_file={$output_file_name}");
    } else {
        header("Location: error.php");
    }
}
```

This is the code. what went wrong exactly? :(

Comment: You're uploading an `.xls` file, while your error message states that only `.xsl` and `.xslx` files are allowed

Comment: @brombeer thats only the output error message that have nothing to do with the logic. If u see the code carefully, u would see i put xls or xlsx for the condition if else

Comment: Right (but then your error message is misleading). Does `error.php` only show **that** particular error? Does it show because the extension is wrong or because `move_uploaded_file` failed?

Comment: @brombeer how 'move_uploaded_file' can be failed when its php function? yes, only show the error.php page which i suspect the program cant get the file existence

Comment: "_how 'move_uploaded_file' can be failed when its php function?_" PHP functions can fail. [move_uploaded_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) can fail for various reasons. Permission settings on the target folder would be my first guess. Have you checked **where** your script fails?

Comment: `how 'move_uploaded_file' can be failed when its php function`...you think PHP functions are magic and can't fail? All functions can fail, if the conditions needed for success are not met, no matter who wrote them. What an odd statement. Anyway if you'd [read the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) you'd know exactly what it can return and exactly what situations can cause it to fail. Any reason you hadn't read the manual?? If you're going to use a function, it's a good idea to read the instructions on how to use it.

Comment: @ADyson not helping but thanks

Answer (score -1):

The "uploads/" directory probably doesn't exist, so move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file_dir) fails.

Comment: I see, how should i fix this?